# Expand/Collapse project drawer folders in TextMate 2

Tags: macos, textmate-2

I don't know what I did, TextMate 2 expanded the entire files of my project in the sidebar. Now the performance drastically went down. I can't able to figure out how to collapse it.

[image: Sidebar/Project Drawer with expanded view]

Comment: I have this problem all the time - I've been manually closing the folders (which gets really old). It seems to be somewhat related to the cmd-opt-n hotkey, as it always happens when I'm doing that. Would really like to see a solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can hold option while clicking the 'Disclosure Arrow' (the little arrow next to the directory name) to recursively collapse all subfolders.

To collapse all the directories without performing the action for every folder, do this:

- Press `control+tab` to move the focus to the file drawer.
- Press `command+up arrow` to 'go up a level'.
- Hold `option` and click the arrow next to your desired folder.
- Click the folder icon next to your desired directory to change the file drawer back to that directory.

Reference:
http://wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2

Answer (score 6):

I don't have TextMate 2, but does selecting the top level items and pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> work? That should be the standard shortcut for collapsing a node recursively but it's not supported by all list views.

Comment: yeah it collapses only for immediate selection :(

Comment: Why did I try this on such a large folder! It does seem to work though, thanks! Works really nice in combination with "Reveal current file" Cmd+Shift+R.

Answer (score 1):

what works for me is:

1. select an item in the project drawer
2. command-a to select all
3. hit the left arrow (right arrow expands all)

that should collapse all folders

Comment: This is great, a step in the right direction. Too bad it only collapses the top level folders though, and maintains the select-all selection when you open them.